# What's the purpose of the modifyMeta() function in ModifierInterface

Tags: xml, magento2.2, meta

I've been trying to add data to the product form.   I've been following [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html) tutorial, as well as looking through the Magento 2 codebase.

My understanding so far:

- The purpose of the **`product_form.xml`** is to build the actual HTML form.
- The purpose of **`AbstractModifier::modifyData`** is to add your data to the product that is passed to the form

However, I don't understand **`AbstractModifier::modifyMeta`**.  It appears to be doing the same thing as the XML, just in a hard-to-read way.  However, *every* module that I look at seems to modify the meta this way as opposed to putting it in XML.

**What is this "meta" we are modifying, and why isn't all of this data where data belongs (XML)?**

Answer (score 5):

Indeed `modifyMeta` changes the structure of the ui-components.
The reason why not everything is in the xml files, is because these files can contain fixed values.
The `modifyMeta` allows adding dynamic data. For example in the product add/edit form you cannot add all attributes in the xml because they can be managed from the backend.

Comment: So, as an example, I've been looking at `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AdvancedInventory.php`.  As far as I can tell, nothing here is dynamic, and all of the "code" is basically getting to the right spot in the XML.  Does it seem like all of this code should be in XML, not `modifyMeta()`?